# Any way to check a certain number of threads have completed

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I have an application where I need at least (for some consistency guarantees) k out of n threads to return.  After that, I'd like the other threads to continue running, but after k threads finish, then I continue along.  I can have a variable that gets incremented at the end of each thread, and then have a spin lock, but I'd prefer to not have a spin lock.  Any suggestions for something else to do?

Comment: I'm not getting what you're asking. What should happen once k threads have finished?

Answer (score 3):

> I can have a variable that gets incremented at the end of each thread

That would work. I recommend doing that.

> and then have a spin lock, but I'd prefer to not have a spin lock

There's no need to use a spin lock. Wait on a [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead.